# How to use left outer join in hibernate to return collection of object

Tags: hibernate

This is my SQL query with a left join:

```
select 
    a.clientid, a.companyname, a.phone, b.emp_id 
from 
    bw_clientdetails a 
left join 
    bw_client_allocation b on a.clientid = b.client_id;
```

How to represent above query using hibernate so that I can use the resulting object list to populate by grid using display tag.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is very similar to the one of SQL. Have you read the [Hibernate reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins)?

```
select a.clientId, a.companyName, a.phone, b.empId
from ClientDetails a left join a.clientAllocation b
```

Comment: hi can u give me very simple example to understand.i read hibernate reference but still unable to understand.

Comment: What don't you understand in the example query I just gave you in my answer?